# Git - How to create a new pull request without history

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

I'm trying to add new changes to a repo that I have forked onto my Desktop. I've already submitted 1 pull request with a branch called `"network"`. However the pull request **has not** been approved yet.

Now I wish to make a new pull request with changes to a different file with a branch called `"barcode"`. Since my old PR has not yet been approved, any changes I make to the `"barcode"` branch include the old commits made in the `"network"` branch.

What I need however is to have the changes made in the new branch `"network"` be excluded from the new branch `"barcode"`.

You can take a look at my pull request here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/pull/9

I know this can't be too hard, I just can't figure out how to do it. I'm guessing that I'm making my new branch `"barcode"` wrongly, where it contains the edits I made in the old branch `"network"`, and so my pull request contains the old commits too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebasing. I'm guessing you branched from the `network` branch when you created the `barcode` branch. That gives your source as the `network` branch. If you want to have a different point of origin you can either checkout master and create the new `barcode` branch from there, or if you've already done the work, you can rebase. Assuming you want to branch off master

```
git checkout barcode
git rebase master
```

Check out [this page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) for how it works.